Performance issue with a view on large tables with more than 25 billion rows
The STG_USR_ACCSS table has more than 25 billion rows. Creating a view by joining other tables, when we query the data from the view, it's taking forever to return the results. Please help me to rewrite the query for the view to increase the performance of the query for faster retrieval of the results.
 CREATE or REPLACE VIEW large_data_vw as
 SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(A,B,C,D,E,F) */ DISTINCT NVL(M.TEST_MR, 
       SUBSTR(C.ID,-8))  MR,NVL(N.TEST_MR, SUBSTR(E.ID,-8))  
        ACS_MR,A.UA_TM,UPPER(F.ABR) TP_OF_ACT
  FROM STG_USR_ACCSS A
            JOIN STG_PAT B ON A.PT_ID=B.PT_ID
            JOIN STG_ID C ON B.T_ID=C.T_ID AND C.TYPE_ID=14567
            JOIN STG_PAT D ON A.WHO_AC=D.PT_ID
            JOIN STG_ID E ON D.T_ID=E.T_ID AND E.TYPE_ID=14567
            JOIN STG_TYPE F ON A.TPE_C=F.TPE_C
            LEFT JOIN STG_MER M ON SUBSTR(C.ID,-8) = M.MR
            LEFT JOIN STG_MER N ON SUBSTR(E.ID,-8) = N.MR  ; 


One thing, the use of SUBSTR in the JOINs kill any benefit of index use, since all rows need to be evaluated by the function. Is there any way to add an explain output of that query to the question? ... I'm not sure what oracle's equivalent of explain is (a mysql/mariadb keyword) to show the query's execution plan.

If you have a performance issue, you'll need to post a query plan, table definitions, index definitions, etc.  And things like the query you are running against this view that you are trying to tune.  Your driving_site hint implies that you are trying to join a local object to tables on a remote database which vastly (vastly) increases the level of difficulty.

Please read this, then [edit] your question.

It seems to me the scale of this operation will require planning production capacity in advance. It seems unlikely that index wizardry is sufficient to get this to work.
